How to remove a prefix none_ from all words having the prefix in Pandas DataFrame after applying a styler
I would appreciate guidance removing the prefix 'none_' from the output of a styled pandas dataframe.
The prefix none_ is being used to identify the words, whose background color need to be changed to grey.
After the identified words' background color has been changed to grey.
I would like to delete prefix none_ from the word.
Here are the data and code.
File1
abcdefg
12345
none_abd
abcdrtyu
File2
abcdefg
none_acd
12345
abcdrtyu
File3
abcdefg
12345
abcdrtyu
none_abcd
File1, File2 and File3 are column headers and the lines below them are rows in panda dataframe.
For cells that have a word starting with the prefix "none_" I would like to change the background color of the cell to light grey.
After changing the background color of the word to grey, I would like to delete the prefix "none_".
And output the data to an html or xlsx doc.
Here is the code:
import pandas as pd

# Create a pandas DataFrame from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.style
def style_highlight_none(v, props=''):
    return props if v.startswith('none_') else None 

s2 = df.style.map(style_highlight_none, props='background-color:lightgrey;')

s2.to_html('output_wa.html', index=False, escape=False) 

The code runs without throwing any error when written like this.
However, the prefix none_ is still present in the output.
When this line of code is added as shown here:
s2 = s2.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('none_', ''))
import pandas as pd
# Create a pandas DataFrame from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.style
def style_highlight_none(v, props=''):
    return props if v.startswith('none_') else None 

s2 = df.style.map(style_highlight_none, props='background-color:lightgrey;')

# Remove the prefix 'none_' from words containing it
s2 = s2.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('none_', ''))

s2.to_html('output.html', index=False, escape=False)

The code returns all manner of errors.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mydir/script/./whatsapp_pathlib_html_output.py", line 111, in 
s2.to_html('output_wa.html', index=False, escape=False)
File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/style.py", line 1345, in to_html
html = obj._render_html(
File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/style_render.py", line 204, in _render_html
d = self._render(sparse_index, sparse_columns, max_rows, max_cols, " ")
File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/style_render.py", line 161, in _render
self._compute()
File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/style_render.py", line 256, in _compute
r = func(self)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/style.py", line 1752, in _apply
self._update_ctx(result)
File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/style.py", line 1560, in _update_ctx
css_list = maybe_convert_css_to_tuples(c)
File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/style_render.py", line 1925, in maybe_convert_css_to_tuples
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Styles supplied as string must follow CSS rule formats, for example 'attr: val;'. '1245-67ABC' was given.

Code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
props = 'background-color:lightgrey;'
out = df.replace(r'^none_', '', regex=True).style.apply(
    lambda x: np.where(df[x.name].str.startswith('none_'), props, '')
)

out:

Example Code
data = {'File1': ['abcdefg', '12345', 'none_abd', 'abcdrtyu'], 'File2': ['abcdefg', 'none_acd', '12345', 'abcdrtyu'], 'File3': ['abcdefg', '12345', 'abcdrtyu', 'none_abcd']}    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


Thanks @Panda Kim much appreciated. The code you provided, produced the desired result.

@Oluvictor then choose answer for others.

Okay @Panda Kim
